# How to parse this JSON into a Map[String, User]?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I want to go from the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Cat",
    "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
    "location": "San Francisco, CA",
    "id_str": "799346"
  },
  {
    "name": "Dog",
    "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174758/v65oai7fxn47qv9nectx_normal.png",
    "location": "San Francisco, CA",
    "id_str": "783214"
  }
]
```

to a `Map[String, User]`, where the key is the name, and the User is the object that looks like this:

```
case class User(name: String, profileImage: String, id: String)
```

I'm using Play and Scala but am struggling to figure out how to do the JSON parsing.

Answer (score 1):

First you can define an instance of the `Reads` type class for your type:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val userReads = (
  (__ \ 'name).read[String] and
  (__ \ 'profile_image_url).read[String] and
  (__ \ 'id_str).read[String]
)(User.apply _)
```

And then you get a `Reads[List[User]]` instance for free that will decode your JSON:

```
Json.parse(jsonString).validate[List[User]]
```

That's not exactly what you want, but you can turn the list into a map pretty easily:

```
Json.parse(jsonString).validate[List[User]].map(_.map(u => u.name -> u).toMap)
```

And now you've got a `JsResult[Map[String, User]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, maybe you can use [argonaut](http://argonaut.io/), it provides more friendly api.

```
val json: String = """[
                     {
                       "name": "Cat",
                       "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
                       "location": "San Francisco, CA",
                       "id_str": "799346"
                     },
                     {
                       "name": "Dog",
                       "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174758/v65oai7fxn47qv9nectx_normal.png",
                       "location": "San Francisco, CA",
                       "id_str": "783214"
                     }
                   ]"""

      import argonaut._, Argonaut._

      case class User(name: String, url: String, location: String, idStr: String)
      implicit def UserCodecJson =
        casecodec4(User.apply, User.unapply)("name", "profile_image_url", "location", "id_str")

      val result = json.decodeValidation[List[User]]

      println(result) //Success(List(User(Cat,http://a0.twimg.com/profile ....
```

The good thing about this result is Scalaz [Validation](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html), because Validation is monad, so you can bind (flatmap) it with other Validation.

Comment: Sorry, but `Validation` isn't a monad. Also, I prefer Argonaut as well, but given that the question explicitly mentions Play I don't see how this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

1 Define you Case class with format:

```
case class User(name: String, profileImage: String, id: String) {
    implicit val jsonFormat: Format[User] = Json.format[User]
}
```

2 parsing your json as List[User]

```
val jsonStr: String = ...
val users = Json.parse(jsonStr).as[List[User]]
```

3 group your List[User] to Map[String, User]

```
val whatYourWant:Map[String, User] = users.groupBy(_.name)
```